# Topshelf does not call service start

Tags: c#, topshelf

I am seeing different behaviour in Topshelf depending on whether I start the application in standalone mode or installed as a service. I have tried Topshelf 3.3.1 and 4.1.

I am using a service that implements ServiceControl, which works fine in standalone mode. When trying to start the installed service, I receive the message that the service took too long to respond to control requests.

```
var resultCode = HostFactory.Run(x =>
{
    x.Service<ServiceControl>(sc =>
    {
        sc.ConstructUsing(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GET INSTANCE!");
            return new WorkerService();
        });
        sc.WhenStarted((s, h) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("START!");
            return s.Start(h);
        });
        sc.WhenStopped((s, h) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("STOP!");
            return s.Stop(h);
        });
        sc.BeforeStartingService(() => Console.WriteLine("BEFORE START!"));
    });

    x.SetDescription("WorkerService");
    x.SetDisplayName("WorkerService");
    x.SetServiceName("WorkerService");
});
```

This is a *very* verbose version of calling a service (with lots of console output), but even the calls to `ConstructUsing` or `BeforeStartingService` do not produce any console output, while log calls inside the `Service<>` lambda produce output.

I am left quite clueless here, but also have not been able to reproduce this with a minimal sample. The timeout comes after about 3-4 seconds, without any visible attempt to start the service. Starting the service thread from the program main does work without exception.

Starting the service with `WorkerService.exe` works as expected, starting it with `WorkerService.exe start` (which starts the service) does not work.

As this happens with Topshelf 3 and 4, it most likely is something I am doing wrong inside the application. Any pointer into the right direction is very much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like something going wrong inside the WorkerService. Isn't that your implementation of ServiceControl?

Comment: It does not even get that far, Topshelf does not even call the `ConstructUsing` lambda (so there is no console log), but only as service, not in standalone

Comment: console log? Aren't you installing this as a windows service via the topshelf command as its said here: http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/commandline.html#examples ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a lead now: as part of loading the config we are loading a file from the roaming AppData and it looks like if the file is not accessible, an exception is thrown and silently discarded. If the file does not exist, the service starts as expected and everything works.

So the basic problem is that an uncaught exception was thrown before the Topshelf service config part was started, which seems to be used to forward some output to the command line application when calling the exe with the start parameter.

I will try to investigate on that as time allows and to contribute to Topshelf with the learnings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered WorkerService as ServiceControl? If not, register the service. (Do you use Autofac?).
If not, try providing

```
x.Service<WorkerService>(sc => // Your code
```

instead of ServiceControl

Comment: The `sc.ConstructUsing()` creates the instance of the service. In standalone mode, this works correctly, I only see this when installed on one server

Comment: I have seen the same issue earlier. For me, the initial implementation had the main work starting out as a task. When I run the exe, everything works as expected, but when I install n run it as service, I used to get the same issue. Would it be possible to post the workerservice code? I think it is something to do with that peice of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register the service in cmd (with admin privileges):

to install: `yourApplication.exe install`
to unistall: `yourApplication.exe uninstall`